# Express/NodeJS: stderr: Error: request entity too large

Tags: node.js, express

There is the following code:

```
var url             = require('url');
var proxy           = require('express-http-proxy');
var localConfig     = require('./config.js');
var frontendRuntime = require('frontend-runtime')(localConfig);
var config          = frontendRuntime.config;
var app             = require('./lib/utils/devServer.js');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: 10 * 1024 * 1024}));
app.use(bodyParser.raw({limit: 10 * 1024 * 1024}));
app.use(bodyParser.text({limit: 10 * 1024 * 1024}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: 10 * 1024 * 1024, extended: true}));

app.use('/some-url', proxy(config.apiEndpointHost, {
  forwardPath: function(req, res) {
    return '/api2' + url.parse(req.url).path;
  }
}));

app.listen(config.portProxy);
console.log('Server started');
```

As you can see I pass 'limit' parameter for bodyParser (I want uploading files), but it didn't work - when I'm trying to upload image with 1.5 Mb size I got the error: "stderr: Error: request entity too large". How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy/issues/27) you don't need bodyParser

```
app.use('/some-url', proxy(config.apiEndpointHost, {
      limit: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
      forwardPath: function(req, res) {
        return '/api2' + url.parse(req.url).path;
      }
    }));
```